# Is it a must to include a random slope in a mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I am learning about fitting mixed models and I find when it is justified to include or exclude a random slope rather confusing.

Some tutorials suggest that although the maximal random structure should be specified at the outset, the random slope should be kept only if it contributes to extra explanatory power, i.e. is significant and hence mathematically justified to stay in the model.

Other papers suggest that the random slope should be kept regardless of its significance when a cross-level interaction effect is included in the model; but does this assertion hold when no cross-level interaction but only a main effect is being investigated? Under what circumstances should I decide to keep or discard the random slope component from my model?

Comment: (+1) can you site some references, and summarise the reasoning, for the argument in the 3rd paragraph ?

Comment: The following papers suggest that omitting the random slope component tends to inflate Type I error when a cross-level interaction term is included: 

Bell, A., Fairbrother, M., &Jones, K. (2019). Fixed and random effects models: making an informed choice. Quality and Quantity, 53(2), 1051–1074. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11135-018-0802-x

Heisig, J. P., &Schaeffer, M. (2019). Why you should always include a random slope for the lower-level variable involved in a cross-level interaction. European Sociological Review, 35(2), 258–279. https://doi.org/10.1093/esr/jcy053

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is considerable disagreement on this topic.

I like to keep it simple. If you have *a priori* reasons to believe that the fixed effect in question *should* vary by subject (or whatever the grouping variable is) then you should fit random slopes. Obviously, this is provided that the data supports such a model. Often a model containing random slopes will have a singular fit, either because the correlation between the slopes and intercepts is estimated close to, or at, +/- 1, or because the variance in the random slopes is estimated close to, or at, 0. In the former case, a model fitted without such correlation can be fitted, but in the latter case the only solution is usually to remove the random slopes.

If the model converges without warnings, then I would retain the random slopes. I would not do any statistical test to decide whether to retain them, because I had *a priori* reasons to include them in the first place and just because they weren't significant in this sample is not a reason to exclude them if I believe they should be present in the population.

Having said that, I can't really argue with the approach of testing with a likelihood ratio, and removing the slopes if they don't offer an improved fit, on the basis of model parsimony. It's just my preference to retain them.

I am not familiar with the argument to retain random slopes if a cross-level interaction is fitted in the fixed part of the model. Does this refer to random slopes for the interaction only ?

Comment: Thank you for answering. So it seems that it's more important to theoretically justify the inclusion of random slopes prior to constructing the model. Now I wonder when people would decide not to fit random slopes in the model at the outset as it seems reasonable that every cluster can respond in different ways to the same stimuli/treatment... 
As for the cross-level interaction question, the papers argue that the random slopes of the level-1 variables should always be included. I just attached two papers discussing this in the question.

Comment: I agree with you. It is often very easy to justify random slopes. Situations where it is more of a reach is for fixed effects like sex which obviously do not vary within subjects

Comment: As for the cross-level interaction question, this site tries to be as self contained as possible so when asking about arguments made in papers plesse try to summarise the substance of the arguments, not just link to the papers.

Comment: The Heisig & Schaffer paper is the one that deals with cross-level interactions. They find in simulation work that the test for significance of the cross-level interaction when the level 1 slope is held fixed is biased in that the p-value tends to be understated  (lower) relative to a model in which the level 1 slope is treated as random. They use the term "anti-conservative" in reference to the first case (fixed slope + cross-level interaction) - one would be more likely to conclude statistical significance when there is none.

Comment: @ErikRuzek thanks. That's interesting.  I will probably do some of my own simulations. Personally I don't use p values at all, so if the effect sizes are unbiased I am not bothered.  I wonder if this p value bias goes away for larger numbers of clusters and/or cluster sizes.

Comment: I hope that you share the results of your simulations, @RobertLong! Heisig & Schaeffer show that the problem actually gets worse at larger sample sizes. https://academic.oup.com/esr/article/35/2/258/5306121#132685273